# Occur mode face for buffer names

Tags: faces, occur, customize-face

The result buffer of `occur` displays the buffer name with some info:

```
69 matches in 65 lines for "use" in buffer: init.el
```

It's alright when I run `occur` in only one buffer.

I just started using `multi-occur` (rather `projectile-multi-occur`), thus getting multiple lines of that type, one per file with matches. I find that these lines should make a greater visual separation. Right now, these lines have the face `underline` (at the bottom of the result of `describe-char`):

[image]

I was expecting a face, which I could change in my theme.

Is this face `underline` hard-coded in the implementation of `occur`? Can I customize it from within my theme file?

Answer (score 1):

You can change `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face` to the face what your want.

```lisp
(defface blue-underline
  '((t :foreground "blue" :underline t))
  "blue-underline face.")

(setq list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face 'blue-underline)
```

---

How I find it:

1. go to source code of `multi-occur`
2. search `underline`

Comment: FYI: I filed Emacs [bug #54157](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=54157), to alias the `list-matching-lines-*` option names to `occur-*` names.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to put this in my `theme.el`: `\`(list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face ((t (:foreground "blue" :underline t))))`, but it doesn't seem to work. Am I missing something? I see that it's not the same way (not using `defcustom`), but all faces in my theme are done as I pasted here.

Comment: @Gauthier Hi, `list-matching-lines-buffer-name-face` is a variable not face. You should use `setq` to set it to some face. I have update my answer with an example.